# Laravel - Oauth password grant

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0

I find it difficult to wrap my head around the password grant authentication process.

**What I'm trying to achieve:** A mobile device sends the username and the password of a registered user to the API and gets the access token as a response in JSON form.

**What I've achieved so far:** The API receives the user credentials (username and password) and authenticates the user using Laravel's built-in Auth authentication system.

I know that at this point I should proceed to Oauth authentication. Once the credentials pass the Auth step, I have the user's username, password (specified in the `users` table) and I can get the `client_id` and `client_secret` from the `oauth_clients` table, but I'm not sure how to accomplish the rest. Do I need to make another POST request? If yes, then how do I do it from the controller?

Comment: What oauth2 package are you using? Can you show some code?

Comment: https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel

Comment: I'll answer this once I get home.

Answer (score 2):

I am actually implementing this right now. Let me show you some code.

This is my part of my login function:

```
// this does the process for getting the access token
$oauth  = AuthorizationServer::performAccessTokenFlow();
// some hacks
$oauth  = (array) $oauth;
// more hacks
$oauth  = json_decode($oauth["\0*\0data"], true);

// checks if a token was actually generated
if(!in_array('bearer', $oauth))
{
    // returns what was generated if the token is missing
    return Responser::error(400, $oauth);
}
```

You would have to post additional data on your login other than the `username` and `password` of the user.

So your post request will contain:

```
username=the_username
password=the_password
grant_type=password
client_id=the_client_id
client_secret=the_client_secret
```

note that `grant_type=password` is constant.

Now you have to check the configurations of the package too found at `app/config/packages/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel/oauth2.php`:

You should have the following code:

```
'password' => array(
    'class'            => 'League\OAuth2\Server\Grant\Password',
    'access_token_ttl' => 604800,
    'callback'         => function($username, $password){

        $credentials = array(
            // change this to username if username is the field on your database
            'email' => $username,
            'password' => $password,
        );

        $valid = Auth::validate($credentials);

        if (!$valid) {
            return false;
        }

        return Auth::getProvider()->retrieveByCredentials($credentials)->id;
    }
),
```

And you are done.

---

**update**

the code above that generates the token is inside this function:

```
// allow user to login with username or email and password
$user_pass  = array('username'  => $username, 'password' => $password);
$email_pass = array('email'     => $username, 'password' => $password);

// check if input is email and use $email_pass combination or else use $user_pass combination
$login = ($isEmail->passes() ? $email_pass : $user_pass);

// try to authenticate username & password
if (Auth::attempt($login))
{
    // now you are authenticated here
    // get the client id and secret from the database
    // maybe use curl or some hacks
    // login stuff and token generation

}
```

Comment: I have done a very similar implementation, only that the whole login process consists of two POST requests: the first one gets the `client_id` and `client_secret` (I authenticate the user using the default laravel Auth to get his/her details) and the second one POSTs data to `oauth/access_token` with all the required data for the password grant type.

Comment: Actually I only have one post, this authenticates the user and also generates the token.

Comment: But how do you know the user's id and secret beforehand? The only way to get this data is by fetching it from the database, which requires you to authenticate the user first.

Comment: What I don't understand is how `AuthorizationServer::performAccessTokenFlow();` gets the POST data from the request. You're not passing it anywhere, are you?

Comment: @doitmyway that is right, I am currently checking the source code if it is possible to pass data instead of using the post request. I will update if I get anywhere

Comment: The reason my script uses the two-step process is because once the first POST request is done, the `AuthorizationServer::performAccessTokenFlow();` part doesn't have the POST data. The problem I can't figure out is how to pass the data to oauth from inside the controller.

Comment: @doitmyway I see what you are trying to say, I too am looking for ways to pass those data as parameters instead. I'm still going over the source code.

Comment: The only way I could implement this right now is by using two POST requests. I don't think there's anything wrong with my solution, but I  was wondering whether it could be done more elegantly. ;)

Comment: @doitmyway True, it seems okay, though there should be a way to do it more elegantly. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of an old post, but if you are looking to do this without having multiple post requests, you could always just do something like:

```
//Get Oauth creds
$apiCreds = OauthClient::where('email', Input::get('email'))->first();

//Provide additional post data for password grant
Input::merge([
    'grant_type' => 'password',
    'client_id' => $apiCreds->id,
    'client_secret' => $apiCreds->secret,
    'username' => Input::get('email'),
    'password' => Input::get('password'),
    'scope' => 'all'
]);

//Login
return AuthorizationServer::performAccessTokenFlow();
```